# Use ObjC block in Swift protocol

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures, objective-c-blocks, swift-protocols

I'm trying to convert code from Objective-C to Swift. It won't be possible to convert all of it, since the project uses C++ and thus also Objective-C++ but at least the used protocols should be written in Swift.

So while trying to convert one with a block as a property I've stumbled over problems.

My Objective-C protocol:

```
@protocol ObjcProtocol<NSObject>

@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy, readwrite) dispatch_block_t callback;

@end
```

My Swift protocol:

```
@objc public protocol SwiftProtocol: NSObjectProtocol {
    var callback: ()->() { get set }
}
```

Trying to set this property in Objective-C I get this error:

"Property 'callback' not found on object of type 'NSObject *'"

The created Swift header file contains this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^ _Nonnull callback)(void);
```

I've also stumbled upon `@convention(block)`. Declaring it directly in the var doesn't work, as I get an error claiming it can only be used as a function type. So I've tried using a typealias:

```
public typealias callBackType = (@convention(block) () -> ())
```

which once again results in the property not being found.

Something else I've tried but had no success, was explicitly annotating the property with `@objc`.

Setting the callback function type to optional also didn't change anything.

Furthermore I've tried creating an Objective-C protocol containing the callback and make the SwiftProtocol depend on the newly created protocol. Same result...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Okay.. so it turned out even though Xcode can auto-complete the code, it doesn't mean, everything is correctly imported in the file. To fix the above I've added `@import <ModuleName.Swift>;` and it works